# Prevent the bash on Windows 10 from inserting slash when hitting tab for completion

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash

When using the Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10, every time you hit the tab for the completion of the name of a file or directory, a slash `/` is always inserted at the end of the file/directory name. 
Is it possible to prevent this behavior ? 
The version I'm using should be: `10.0.14393.0`

Comment: The `/` is only added when completing folder names, so you can keep traversing the directory structure.

Comment: That's the matter, the slash is added also when completing file names

Comment: When you ask about Ubuntu on Windows (aka WSL) please be sure to always mention its version. It is under development and gets updated often.

Comment: Sure @ddbug, I've just updated the question